# Error Installing symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to install simfony 2 (with php 5.6.15) but I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Murilo\Desktop\teste>php -r "readfile('https://symfony.com/installer');
" > symfony

C:\Users\Murilo\Desktop\teste>php symfony

Warning: readfile(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify faile
d in Command line code on line 1

Warning: readfile(): Failed to enable crypto in Command line code on line 1

Warning: readfile(https://symfony.com/installer): failed to open stream: operati
on failed in Command line code on line 1
```

Listening php modules:

```
C:\Users\Murilo\Desktop\teste>php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

This is my first day using PHP and I don't have idea how to solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've not a `cert.pem` file. Open your console and run

```
php -r "var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());"
```

[openssl_get_cert_locations](http://php.net/manual/it/function.openssl-get-cert-locations.php) is available from PHP 5.6, and it retrieve the available certificate locations. On my Fedora I get something like this:

```
array(8) {
  ["default_cert_file"]=>
  string(21) "/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem"
  ["default_cert_file_env"]=>
  string(13) "SSL_CERT_FILE"
  ["default_cert_dir"]=>
  string(18) "/etc/pki/tls/certs"
  ["default_cert_dir_env"]=>
  string(12) "SSL_CERT_DIR"
  ["default_private_dir"]=>
  string(20) "/etc/pki/tls/private"
  ["default_default_cert_area"]=>
  string(12) "/etc/pki/tls"
  ["ini_cafile"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ini_capath"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

You may want check if the `default_cert_file` file (in my case `/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem`) exists. If not, you can use [this](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem).

Comment: the path of the file.

Comment: why you want edit it? you really should not move yours certificates

Comment: I created this file in the path ["default_cert_file"]=>string(25) "c:/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem" but the error continues.

Comment: No, I will do it now

Answer (score 0):

This definitely is not related to Symfony. For me a related bug was solved by disabling SSLv2 and SSLv3 on your system's SSL configuration. See http://disablessl3.com/